# Hindi letters in Unity Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making Hindi Letter sorting game for which i have created an array of few words and then i have created an array of letters used to make that word.
I am trying to place this string on the text component of unity editor but its accepting this string on one PC while it ignores it on another

```
    private string[] questions = {"टप","टब","वक","कप","रख","पर","खत","भर","दस","एक","धन","ईख","हल","फल","जल","जग","वन","नट","पथ","नथ","रथ","बस","घर","छत","उठ","ठग","ऊन","धम","नभ","जप","तट","कद","थक","दक","औस"};
    private string[] characters = { "ट", "प", "ब", "व", "क", "र", "ख", "भ", "द", "स", "ए", "ध", "न", "ई", "ह", "ल", "फ़", "ज", "ग", "थ", "छ", "त","ठ", "ऊं", "म", "औ"}; 
   void NextLevel(string question)
    {
        int temp_1, temp_2, temp_3, temp_4;
        missing = question.Substring(0, 1);
        missing1 = question.Substring(1, 1);
        print(question);
        do
        {
            random_1 = Random.Range(0, 25);
        }
        while (characters[random_1].Equals(missing) || characters[random_1].Equals(missing));
        temp_1 = random_1 / 7;
        if (temp_1 == 0)
            Top_Left_Text.text = missing;
        if (temp_1 == 1)
            Top_Right_Text.text = missing;
        if (temp_1 == 2)
            Bottom_Left_Text.text = missing;
        if (temp_1 == 3)
            Bottom_Right_Text.text = missing;
        temp_2 = temp_1;
        do
        {
            random_2 = Random.Range(0, 25);
            temp_2 = random_2 / 7;
        } while (temp_2.Equals(temp_1) || characters[random_2].Equals(missing) || characters[random_2].Equals(missing1) || (temp_2 * 7 / 9).Equals(checkprevrandom));
        if (temp_2 == 0)
            Top_Left_Text.text = missing1;
        if (temp_2 == 1)
            Top_Right_Text.text = missing1;
        if (temp_2 == 2)
            Bottom_Left_Text.text = missing1;
        if (temp_2 == 3)
            Bottom_Right_Text.text = missing1;
        temp_3 = temp_2;
        do
        {
            random_3 = Random.Range(0, 25);
            temp_3 = random_3 / 7;
        } while (temp_3.Equals(temp_2) || temp_3.Equals(temp_1) || characters[random_3].Equals(missing) || characters[random_3].Equals(missing1));
        temp_4 = temp_3;
        do
        {
            random_4 = Random.Range(0, 25);
            temp_4 = random_4 / 7;
        } while (temp_4.Equals(temp_3) || temp_4.Equals(temp_2) || temp_4.Equals(temp_1) || characters[random_4].Equals(missing) || characters[random_4].Equals(missing1));
        checkprevrandom = temp_2 * 7 / 9;
        Bottom_Right.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = letters[temp_2];
        Bottom_Right.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colorChoice[Random.Range(0, colorChoice.Length)];
        Bottom_Left.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = letters[temp_1];
        Bottom_Left.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colorChoice[Random.Range(0, colorChoice.Length)];
        Top_Right.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = letters[temp_3];
        Top_Right.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colorChoice[Random.Range(0, colorChoice.Length)];
        Top_Left.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = letters[temp_4];
        Top_Left.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colorChoice[Random.Range(0, colorChoice.Length)];
        Letter_Answer_1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = letters[temp_4];
        Letter_Answer_2.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = letters[temp_2];
        if (temp_1 != 0 && temp_2 != 0)
            Top_Left_Text.text = characters[random_1];
        if (temp_1 != 1 && temp_2 != 1)
            Top_Right_Text.text = characters[random_2];
        if (temp_1 != 2 && temp_2 != 2)
            Bottom_Left_Text.text = characters[random_3];
        if (temp_1 != 3 && temp_2 != 3)
            Bottom_Right_Text.text = characters[random_4];
    }
```

Comment: it's a good question

Answer (score 0):

Unity UI Text claimes to be unicode capable but it's not in full range unicode support. You can use the following code that extends the native text element to be able using unicode:

[Unity Text UTF32 Extension](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/image-fonts-fontawesome.281746/#post-2653076)

Then you are at least be able to directly display unicode letter such as `\uf204` (just an usage example)